# Running rbtimer from emperor

Tags: python, uwsgi

I have a web application managed by an emperor and two distinct vassals. Because they both write to different data sources, I need a file to synchronise both and so I've decided to add a timer job to my emperor.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
strict = True
die-on-term = True
memory-report = True
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
emperor = xxx.ini
logdate = True
import = synchronize
```

And this is `synchronize.py`:

```
from uwsgidecorators import rbtimer, lock
INTERVAL = 10

@lock
@rbtimer(INTERVAL)
def synchronize():
    """ Synchronizes data between Redis and PostgreSQL. """
    print 'AAA'
```

I run my emperor thus: `uwsgi --ini emperor.ini` but nothing happens, the console never prints 'AAA'.

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a process (a worker or a mule) to run the signal handler. Spawn a worker (adding a socket directive) or a mule (adding mule = true). In the case of a mule you need to add target=mule to the @rbtimer decorator)